# Modeling Database tables based on constraints

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have this table model, how do i normalize it so that given constraint is satisfied.

```
VendorID ProductID Fields       Type       Value

123      P1        Expiry       Date       2018-01-01
123      P1        Quantity     Number     45
123      P1        Origin       Text       ALASKA
123      P2        Owner        Text       JEFF
123      P2        Origin       Text       OHIO
145      P1        Quantity     Number     32
```

**Constraint** : **Type** Column can be only from a given set of types.

I want any no of fields can be added but it should only be from some defined type like( text, number, date,..). How can i model this table/tables?

i tried to give every field type an ID

```
fieldtype  ID

Text       123
Date       345
Number     678
```

and reference it with associated fields.

```
Field       FieldID

Quantity      678
Location      123
```

But i am getting confused as in how do i store related field values so that the constraint is always valid( constraint being fields can only be from defined field types).

To store field values and to enforce the constraint i thought of designing a table with field types as columns but it will give me lot of null values as shown below:

```
Text         Number         Date         Field      VendorID
Melbourne     NULL          NULL         LOCATION     V1

NULL          36            NULL         QUANTITY     V1

NULL          NULL          2017-01-01   EXPIRY       V1
```

I do not need commands , just the basic schema that can help me visuzlize this situation better.

additional info: These fields are further to be associated with vendors where any vendor can define fields for any products he has. so in short, there can be any no of vendors and for any product he has he can define fields

Comment: Can't you just use ENUM for this?

Comment: @Herco thanks.ENUM can be used , thanks but how do i actually insert the values as value column has data of different types

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ENUM eg:

```
  CREATE TABLE your_table (
      VendorID int,
      type ENUM('Date', 'Number', 'Text'),
      .....
  );
```

and use this it way

```
  INSERT INTO your_table  (vendorId ,type, value) VALUES (123,'date','2018-01-01' );
  INSERT INTO your_table  (vendorId ,type, value) VALUES (123,'Number', 45);
```

or in single insert

```
INSERT INTO your_table  (vendorId ,type, value) 
 VALUES (123,'date','2018-01-01' ), 
        (123,'Number', 45);
```

and select

```
  SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE type = 'Number';
```

see this ref form more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

In general depend of your application need  .. 
If you need  restrict the admitted  values in more tables  and these values are static you can assign the related  enum to each table  ..

Comment: @scalsEdge Thanks.but how do i insert values in value column. it has different types. also is one table sufficient keeping in mind the queries like: 1) finding all products of a vendor.
2) Find fields of a product by a given vendor

Comment: The sample ypu suggest seems based onb relation between the tables a nd for this the join with the main table can permit the filter you need  but   Depend of your application need  . ..i have added  a brief suggestion  ..  hope is useful

Comment: @scalsEdge frgive me for my noobiness but how do i actually insert the values as value column has data of different type

Comment: based on your sample you can insert the rows you needc as suggested in my answer ... answer updated for this

Comment: @scalsEdge thanks again, but just a quick question does that mean a column can have any type as values? specially in here what is the type defination for `value` field
`CREATE TABLE your_table (
      VendorID int,
      type ENUM('Date', 'Number', 'Text'),
      value ???????
  ); `

Comment: If you want use  this struc the value column must be a string for host each type of data .. eg varchar(255) if you need  potentially a value for max 255 char

Comment: @scalsEdge that is the problem if i make each column as string it would become very difficult to run analytics .ex: all quantity < 40 or find all expiry < 2018-01-01. This is the main issue i am facing.

Comment: This is the tipycal problem related to the use of mixed  value content .. ..and there is not a pratical solution because the altrnative could be the use of different tables for omogeneus data type related to vender ??   ..BAD idea ..  ..when you need  a proper filter you can use proper cast based on the type filte .. so you can cast  the string '40' in interr and perform you filter on this value .. and so on for date .. etc..